# Problem with redirection of shop subcategories in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I couldn't find an answer, how to redirect certain subcategories...

I've old shop with paths like that:

- shop.com/old_cat1/old_cat2/old_cat3

What I want, is to redirect it like that:

- shop.com/new_cat2
- shop.com/new_cat3

When I'm trying to use this code:

```
Redirect 301 /old_cat1/old_cat2/ https://shop.com/new_cat2
Redirect 301 /old_cat1/old_cat2/old_cat3 https://shop.com/new_cat3
```

redirection from old_cat2 to new_cat2 is working, but redirection to new_cat3 is sending me to new_cat2 (higher level). What should I do? I was trying with RedirectMatch, but it gave me nothing.

Comment: `Redirect` works based on path _prefixes_, so the first one here matches `/old_cat1/old_cat2/old_cat3` already. So you would need to reverse the order here - go from more specific, to less specific.

Comment: Thank You @CBroe! I hoped, that it'll be something easy to deal with!